# Delphi, switching from [Uni]SynEdit to SyntaxMemo SDK

Tags: delphi, syntax-highlighting, synedit

we're about to switch from SynEdit (Unicode version) to SyntaxMemo SDK, however prior to the final decision we need to estimate the real cost of the switch. We've been using custom syntax highlighter for SynEdit built to suit our needs. Now it'll be neccessary to rewrite it, in order to work with SyntaxMemo SDK.
We have already been in contact with an author of  SyntaxMemo SDK, however he admitted he doesn't know SynEdit well, thus he might not answer the question - **Is it possible to create SyntaxMemo lexer similar to SynEdit highlighter** or do we have to redesign it and write from scratch?
Is there anybody around who had ever dealed with this kind of "conversion"?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using Scintilla instead. I converted one app that used SynEdit to use Scintilla. It is easy to create a lexer in Scintilla but Scintilla works in different way when compared to SynEdit. I recommend Scintilla since is being actively developed and is used by many projects. Worth taking a look at it.

I know I am not answering your question but I think my experience converting from SynEdit might be helpful.